# How to order set<pair<unsigned int, double> > by the second value of pair?

Tags: c++, set

As the title says, I've built a `set` of `pair` of values that I need ordered by the `double value` (second):

`set<pair<unsigned int, double> > s`

Comment: Have you tried [`std::sort`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/)?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2958226/how-do-i-create-a-set-with-stdpair-thats-sorted-based-on-the-second-pair-mem ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should use the comparator:

```
struct Cmp
{
    bool operator ()(const pair<unsigned int, double> &a, const pair<unsigned int, double> &b)
    {
        return a.second < b.second;
    }
};
```

and then you can define your set like:

```
set <pair<unsigned int, double>, Cmp> your_set;
```

Answer (score 2):

`set`, in fact, has three parameters, the last two of which are optional. But in your case you want to use the second parameter, which tells how the elements will be sorted. By default (ignoring the third parameter), a `set` is:

`set<typename Key, typename Compare = less<Key>>`

You just need to write an appropriate class for the second parameter, such as:

```
template<typename Pair>
class CompareSecond
{
  bool operator()(const Pair& firstPair, const Pair& secondPair)
  {
    return firstPair.second < secondPair.second;
  }
}
```

And then you construct your `set` as:

```
typedef pair<unsigned int, double> MyPair;
set<MyPair, CompareSecond<MyPair>> s;
```

Answer (score 1):

In C++11 you will probably want to use a lambda. Unfortunately it is not possible to get the type of lambda in an unevaluated context. So we need to cheat a little to get argument deduction:

```
#include <set>

template<typename T, typename Cmp>
std::set< T, Cmp > make_set(Cmp cmp) {
  return std::set<T, Cmp>(cmp);
}

int main()
{
  auto s = make_set<std::pair<int, int> >( 
    [](const std::pair<int, int>& p1, const std::pair<int, int>& p2) 
    { return p1.second < p2.second; } );

  return 0;
}
```

`make_set` is a nice functor to have around but it wont work if you
need to specify the allocator for the `set`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a map instead of set. With a key doulbe and value unsigned int. 
std::map< double, unsigned int > s;